# Метод splice не успевает (js)

Tags: javascript

Вот разметка

```
<button style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></button>
```

А вот сам скрипт

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var array = ['один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять', 'десять', 'одиннадцать', 'двенадцать'];
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
btn.onclick = function(){
    var random = getRandomInt(0, array.length);
    console.log(array[random]);
    array.splice(random, 1);
}
```

Периодически выводится значение undefined. Я не могу понять почему это происходит. Скажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее решить

Comment: Потому что `array[array.length]` это всегда `undefined`, для любого массива.

Comment: `getRandomInt(0, array.length-1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

вот ваша функция

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

давайте посмотрим, что происходит с массивом из 10 элементов -

вы вызываете так:

```
getRandomInt(0, 10)
```

и значит будет возвращено:

```
Math.random() * (10 - 0 + 1)) + 0 = 11 * Math.random()
```

Допустим `Math.random()` сгенерирует `0,999`, в результате получится `10` и вы обращаетесь к 10 элементу, но в массиве из 10 элементов лишь 0..9 индексы

Так что формула по хорошему должна быть все таки

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Comment: Ну тут нобелевку надо мне кажется. Спасибо больше за подробный ответ.

Comment: Вы сделали функцию, область значений которой не включает max. С учётом того, что getRandonInt - растиражированное решение, включающее max - лучше всё-таки чинить точку вызова.

Comment: @Al-Tamir А еще полезно оставлять в функции комментарий, о чем она. Чтобы потом не приходилось в голове прокручивать формулы) "выдает случайное целое число от min включительно до max не включительно". У вас max был включен.